# What does "Doze" really do? And should apps change their code because of it?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze

### Background

Android 6 has introduced a built in mechanism called "Doze" for better handling the battery while the device sleeps.

### The problem

Problem is, I don't see how it really works, and how should apps change to handle this new mechanism, if at all.

Obviously, it depends on what you have in the code, but what should I look for?

### What I've found

I've found 2 web pages talking about this :

- https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/94jCkmG4jff
- http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

But they mostly talk about alarms:

> To help with scheduling alarms, Android 6.0 (API level 23) introduces
>   two new AlarmManager methods: setAndAllowWhileIdle() and
>   setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(). With these methods, you can set alarms
>   that will fire even if the device is in Doze.

### The questions

What should apps developer do in order to handle this new mechanism? Would scheduling APIs work differently because of it? How about changes needed for :

1. Alarms
2. Background/foreground service
3. Wakelocks
4. JobScheduler and GcmTaskService

Are there any adjustments that need to be done to handle Android 6 and above in this matter?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important behavior changes is the lack of network connectivity while in idle mode due to Doze. However, there are a whole host of changes to behavior—including wakelocks and JobScheduler jobs.

The developer docs are fairly clear with what won't work while in Doze: 
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#restrictions

If you're looking for specifics, feel free to check out this Gist I've written up about some of my observations of Doze and idle mode behavior:
https://gist.github.com/ccpmark/430d4ddf3a46a02672c1

Comment: Is it possible that the whitelist will help for network?

Comment: As far as I know, the whitelist is only for App Standby mode, not Doze.
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2225

Comment: I don't know. They speak there about Alarms, but the docs say "An app that is whitelisted can use the network and hold partial wake locks during Doze and App Standby" . source: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases

Comment: I'm sorry - I was mistaken. It seems like the whitelist allows you to circumvent Doze.

Comment: But only for specific things, like partial wakelocks, right?